# How did Sophie get on the bus to Halloweentown?

Tags: halloweentown

The youngest of the Cromwell children, Sophie, states that she followed her siblings onto the bus to Halloweentown.

> **Marnie:** *How did you get here?*
>
> **Sophie:** ***I followed you onto the bus***
>
> **Dylan:** *But you were asleep*

**If that's the case, how come her grandmother did not see her get on the bus if she used the front door? Or if she used the back door how come Marnie and Dylan didn't see her get on?**

Comment: Halloween magic, I expect.

Answer (score 1):

Having watched the scene several times (and having learned more about the non-existence of luggage compartments on [1936 Dodge 1½-Ton Wayne buses](https://www.imcdb.org/v120971.html) than I ever thought possible), I can say that you're **completely right**. Grandma Aggie gets on the bus and sits directly on the front seat. The door closes immediately in front of her. The two Cromwell children climb in through the rear door, close the door behind them and sit on the rear seat with the emergency door directly behind them. Unless there was a cut/deleted scene, there's simply no possible way the younger sibling could have sneaked onto the bus without either the grandma or her brother/sister noticing her doing so.

So how then *did she* get to Halloweentown? My guess is that she was holding onto ***the back of the bus*** and standing on the bumper, presumably aided by her natural witch magic to stop her from falling off.

[image]